# Who was the caller in the episode "Last Call" (S03E15)

Tags: plot-explanation, person-of-interest

In the Person of Interest episode S03E15, the POI was Sandra Nicholson, who works in a 911-dial in station. She was forced by a caller to delete calls from a certain date from the server.

At the end of the episode, the POI as well as the caller are alive. Finch gets a phone call from him that he will be after Finch

> You, however, are another story entirely. Be seeing you.

**Who was this caller? Was he ever mentioned after that?** (Maybe I have missed something, but as of today's screened episodes, I have not seen him again).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mysterious criminal mastermind known as **The Voice** has returned in the fifth season, in the [Sotto Voce](http://personofinterest.wikia.com/wiki/Sotto_Voce) episode (S05E09).

A bit more detailed answer with **spoilers**:

> The Voice is actually Terry Easton, the POI of the episode. Terry pretends to be a victim of The Voice and orchestrates an assassination of his former employee. Although The Voice escapes the police once again, he meets his end at the hands of Elias.